# Is there a way to display week numbers aside the weeks in Angular material date picker.,

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker, angular10, angular-material-datetimepicker

I would like to know whether we have a solution to display week numbers along with date in mat-datepicker
please give answers specific to mat-datepicker(Angular material)
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Answer (score 1):

That is not supported natively and building a whole component would be a lot of work. However here is a link to instructions how you could do it yourself: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/20530#issuecomment-886925173

Comment: Thanks Joosen., let me try.,
hope this'll help a lot